# "cannot focus element" exception while trying to upload an attachment using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

While trying to upload an attachment, trying to send the keys instead of opening the OS based file explorer window as sending the path to the file would be easy.

Tried with different element identifiers, still not able to send the keys. mentioned the element HTML below.

Attached the image of element.
[image]

Tried Below Xpath,

```
//*[@id='fileListVideo']//*[starts-with(@class,'qq-upload-button')]
```

Error Log:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.39.562713 (dd642283e958a93ebf6891600db055f1f1b4f3b2),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.4 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'nagarjunaMBP.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:c2e:b816:67ae:922b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.4', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.39.562713 (dd642283e958a9..., userDataDir: /var/folders/g4/dylg4g7s7wb...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 66.0.3359.181, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 38b991ebd4acf37fd0aefaef902853f9
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:276)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:51)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.sendKeys(Unknown Source)
    at actions.PublishBroadcast.MediaLibAction.uploadVideos(MediaLibAction.java:76)
    at stepDefinitions.Publish.SDMediaLibrary.Upload_an_Image(SDMediaLibrary.java:43)
    at ✽.When Upload an Image(features/publish/mediaLibrary/MediaLibrary.feature:10)
```

Comment: which language you are using ?

Comment: Do not use `div` for sending path to file. Try `//input[@type='file']` instead of `//*[@id='fileListVideo']//*[starts-with(@class,'qq-upload-button')]`

Comment: @Andersson tried input as well. //*[@id='fileListVideo']//*[input[@type='file']], but still same

Comment: @cruisepandey using java

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy , `//*[@id='fileListVideo']//*[input[@type='file']]` is definitely not the same as `//input[@type='file']`. Your XPath still returns you `div`, not `input` !!!

Comment: @Andersson this seems to be working `//*[@id='fileList']//*[@type='file']` . Getting this exception `unknown error: path is not absolute: src/test/resources/testData/twt_Pic.jpg` but this seems to be a different error. The file resides in the same project

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to upload a file, and the page uses the standard upload mechanisms provided by HTML, you can do this directly with Selenium itself. The standard HTML mechanism is with an `<input type=‘file’>` element. Once you’ve found that file upload element on the page, you can use `element.sendKeys(“full/path/and/file/name/here”);`

where element would be :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(input[type='file']));
```

Comment: not working. got this error, "unknown error: Element <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> is not clickable at point (268, 162). Other element would receive the click: <div class="loader-container" id="ajaxLoaderContainer" style="opacity: 0.252271;">...</div>". What would be the css for the xpath "//*[@id='fileList']//*[input[@type='file']]"

Comment: Try to add wait before sending

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy : When you are doing it manually , are you performing scroll down or any other kind of action to click on upload button.

Comment: @cruisepandey this webpage is very short. No need to scroll down

Comment: input[name='file'][type='file'] try this cssSelector.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying with the path to div which will not accept the values. So changes the path to input value `//*[@id='fileList']//*[@type='file']`  or `//*[@id='fileList']//input[@type='file']` this worked.

[Thanks to @Andersson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4549554/andersson)